# "Remove the following redirect chain if possible" on Nginx

Tags: nginx, ssl, http, redirect, https

I ran Pingdom test on my 1 plain html file site and I get F rating for this:

Remove the following redirect chain if possible:

```
http://example.com/
http://www.example.com/
https://www.example.com/
```

And the only redirect in my .conf I have is:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com;
  return 301 $scheme://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

Next block is SSL and and the rest.

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  etc...
}
```

There are no other configs. All I need is to redirect non-www to www and always https only and pass the test.

Updated: Full .conf

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com;
  return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;

  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+CHACHA20:EECDH+AES128:RSA+AES128:EECDH+AES256:RSA+AES256:EECDH+3DES:RSA+3DES:!MD5';
  ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparams.pem;
  ssl_session_timeout 1d;
  ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
  ssl_stapling on;
  ssl_stapling_verify on;
  add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;

  root /var/www/example.com/htdocs;

  server_name example.com www.example.com;

  location / {
    autoindex on;
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }

  location ~* /img/.*\.gif$ {
    expires 30d;
    add_header Pragma public;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post all relevant server definitions, in case there are some you haven't noticed that are relevant. For example, the www subdomain doesn't have a listener, but it may be picked up because it's the default site (first server in config by default I think).

Comment: Updated with full conf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change `$scheme` to `https`, I can't tell why that's there in the first place since you're unlikely to get anything other than `http` over port 80 unless your users are doing something weird.

EDIT: Add missing https->https redirect.

Didn't notice you don't actually have an explicit `default_server`.
Go with something along the lines of:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com www.example.com;
  return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
server {
  listen 443;
  server_name example.com;
  return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

Ashish's answer might work but I'd stay away from `if` as much as possible (read [If is Evil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/)).

Comment: I think you're missing a negation there. I'd say it's unlikely *not* to get http over port 80.

Comment: Hi, I did and it only removed `http://www.example.com/` from the list and I still get an F.

Comment: also does not redirect from `https://example.com` to `https://www.example.com`

Answer (score -1):

I guess your godaddy cname or A records will be fine for nginx try the below code.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != 'https') {
          rewrite ^(.*) https://www.example.com$1 redirect;
    }
}
```

If you want to do it in one go then use this way but it is very bad way to solve this issue. Add map module on top of config and location block on server 80 block.

```
map $http_host $new {
    'www.abc.com' '1';
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != 'https') {
        rewrite ^(.*) https://$host$1 redirect;
    }
    location / {
        if ($new != '1') {
            rewrite ^(.*) https://www.example.com$1 redirect;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what it has to do with godaddy, i'm on vultr with namescheap.

Comment: also does not redirect from `https://example.com` to `https://www.example.com`

Comment: If user want to enforce all non www to www only then best is to use godaddy redirection. From you godaddy dns manager can permanently redirect to https and www no need to add in nginx.

Comment: In my new code block location match will be present in both 80 and 443

Comment: One does not want to use `if` in cases like this when it can be easily avoided.